# Has Link ever had a male fairy companion?

Tags: legend-of-zelda-series

As a player of only a few games in the series, I have experienced games where Link has, and has not had a fairy companion.

However, in the games where he has had a fairy companion, they have only ever been female. In fact the only game I have seen a male fairy was in Majora's Mask, when Tael (male) and Ta'tl (female) were accompanying the Skull Kid, then got separated and Ta'tl joined up with Link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**. Well, not *really*.

Link has a fairy companion in Ocarina of Time, Majora's Mask, and Phantom Hourglass, and all of them are female.

That said, Link's traveling companion is not *always* female. In The Minish Cap, Ezlo (the eponymous minish cap) is male, but not really a fairy. In The Wind Waker, the King of Red Lions is also male, but, again, not a fairy.

Comment: Point of order: I didn't forget Midna and Fi: Midna is a Twili, and Fi is a sword.

Comment: I'm not even sure if there exist any male fairies.

Comment: @YUNOWORK: Tael, Tatl's brother, was a male fairy. He also wanted to become Link's companion for a minute, before Tatl decided to stay.

Comment: Also, don't forget Tingle, not a fairy per se.

Comment: @YUNOWORK If you read the question you'll find that yes, there are male fairies ;)

Comment: @Kyrremann not really a companion. Technically he's a merchant, like any other shop owner, he just appears in multiple locations